# BIOS Update from Vista only?

Tags: windows-10, motherboard, windows-vista, bios

I found this old HP Pavilion Media Center m8100 PC and want to do a BIOS update. I found the official BIOS update from [HP on their website here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-pavilion-media-center-m8100-desktop-pc-series/3440688). The motherboard I'm using is IPIBL-LA. I might do the LGA 771 mod on this motherboard in the future so I need the BIOS update for that. Please don't advise me to not just do it.

However, the website says it's only compatible with Windows Vista. I just installed Windows 10 on this machine. Since the updater is an .exe file, I'm not able to perform an update in the BIOS itself or through DOS.

My question is, will the update work on Windows 10 as well or could it potentially brick the motherboard?

Comment: If it works on Vista it will work on Windows 10

Comment: I agree with @Ramhound, but you might need to run the file in [compatibility mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15078/windows-make-older-programs-compatible) also.